# Не отображается клавиатура

Tags: android, webview

Моё приложение содержит `ViewPager` и динамически создаваемые `WebView`. Когда на страничке отображается каптчер (зашита от ботов) для ввода, то при нажатии на компоненте для ввода не отображается клавиатура. Когда убрал `ViewPager` и оставил просто `WebView`, то клавиатура отображалась. В чём может быть проблема?

```
 adapter=new BrowserPagerAdapter(pages);
    viewpager=new ViewPager(this);
    viewpager.setAdapter(adapter);
    viewpager.setCurrentItem(0);
    setContentView(viewpager);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
/**
 * показываем программную клавиатуру
 */
protected void showInputMethod() {
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    if (imm != null) {
        imm.showSoftInput(myEditText, 0);
    }
}
```

**ГЗВ**

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED,0);
```

Comment: Тут задаётся для собственного EditText,мне нужно чтобы при фокусировки на компонент EditText страницы отображалась клавиатура.

Comment: это просто метод, его можно вызвать при любом действии

Comment: повесь на него кликЛистенер и по нажатию вызывай метод... код покажи..

Comment: код большой,какая часть кода тебя интересует?В showSoftInput что передавать первому параметру?

Comment: попробуй лучше так, обновил ответ

Comment: повешай его на какаето событие, возможно после onCreate() клаву ктото прячет

Comment: Выяснил что когда в onCreate() создаеться первый WebView и добаляеться в адаптер,он выводит отображает клавиатуру,а те WebView которые создаються  динамически они не отображают.Шас выясняю что не так сделал.